# Axioms of probability with finite (rather than countable) additivity

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, definition

Probability measures are required to satisfy

- $\mu(\emptyset) = 0$
- $\mu(\Omega) = 1$
- $\mu\left(\bigcup_{i \in \mathbb{N}} A_i \right) = \sum_{i\in \mathbb{N}} \mu(A_i)$ for disjoint sets $A_i \subset \Omega$.

What happens if we only assume the last condition for finite sequences? Do we lose (lots of or all) important results?

Comment: One cool thing that this allows is uniform measures on the reals and integers.

Comment: Can you point me to some details on this please?

Comment: If you can get access, this is a good resource https://www.jstor.org/stable/2291075